Sounddevice playrec with precise repeatable timing
I am trying to do a simultaneous playback and recording on an ASIO device using the sounddevice library (version 0.4.7 because version 0.5.0 does not support ASIO anymore...), with the playrec function.
I need precise recording, but sometimes the function returns data which is shifted by one sample (totally random).
I tried all parameters of playrec as well as using streams, but nothing worked. MATLAB is doing it correctly, so I don’t think it is a hardware issue.
Also, it seems that the recording always starts at the same moment, but it's the playback that is delayed.
What is the origin of that glitch?
